# How to make a single-page template?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, bootstrap

I want to make a single-page template from scratch, but I don't really know where to start. I'm using Joomla 3.x, so my approach should be bootstrap compatible.

I guess that since the menu buttons make the page scroll, it makes sense to use modules for every menu item. But then I wonder how I can get the scrolling and anchors to work properly.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If it's a single page, are you sure Joomla is the right choice for you?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify what you mean by "single-page" template, do you want all your articles / contents on one page?

Comment: @Lodder: I was kind of asking myself the same thing. I want to offer some dev tools for Joomla, and I wouldn't feel okay saying Joomla is great and then using something else. Besides, I already know how to tweak Joomla to my liking, and this would only be my landing page. The other pages would follow a more traditional approach.

Comment: @RasmusBoie: I mean to have my page scroll when I click on a menu item, instead of redirecting to a different page. The point is that I don't want to hard-code this, but I'd rather have it working for any menu and content that I choose from within Jooma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

**Menu items**

Create all menu items as `System Links > External URL` and set link as `#section-[MODULE_ID_HERE]`.

For example your menu links should look like this

```
<a href="#section-[MODULE_ID_HERE]">First section</a>
```

**Modules**

I would create new chrome for modules, so they would all have unique ID attribute. For example with module ID or alias. Then you can link to them.

> Joomla! docs for [module chromes](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Ancillary_Customisation:Chrome).

Module wrapper div should look like this.

```
<div id="#section-<?php echo $module->id; ?>">
    <!-- Module content here -->
</div>
```

`section-` prefix is just for example, you don't have to use this.

**Scrolling**

I found a short example. This prevents regular event on clicking link and animates browser to right section.

```
/**
 * @author Paul Underwood
 * @source http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```