# Scroll to a section or module

Tags: jquery, joomla-3.4

Yes i know this has been asked before here but i cannot seem to get an answer from the suggested solutions. I am trying to create one of the items in my Main menu to scroll to certain section on my website. The code that i am using which i have inserted just before closing of the body tag is as shown

```
 
var $root = jQuery('html, body');
jQuery('#t3-banner').click(function() {
    var href = jQuery.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 2000, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

The section that i am trying to scroll to is the #t3-banner. On the menu item (which i have created as an external menu)i have added the #t3-banner in the link section.But it doesn't seem to work. I am not very good in j query. Could anyone here help me please.The site is this And the menu is let us hunt for you

Comment: If you were able to provide a link to your website for a live preview so we can inspect the code, I think we'll be able to provide you with a concrete solution ;)

Comment: [Here's the link](http://cheaphouses.co.ke/). The menu item i am working with is **Let us hunt for you**. When clicked it should go to banner **Getting started** at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `jQuery('#t3-banner')` is wrong. This should be selector for your `<a>`, which has attribute `href="#t3-banner"`.

It would work with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
        // Don't follow the link, orherwise it would jump to section without animation
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 2000, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
    });
});
```

Code has to be in `jQuery(document).ready`, because event listener can only be added if DOM is ready.

It selects all `<a>` elements, what have `#` in `href`.

NOTE: Beware, it takes ALL `<a>` elementson whole page. If you only want it for menu, you should make your selector more specific.

For example if your menu wrapper has ID `menu`, then it could be `jQuery('#menu a[href^="#"]')`.

You can take a look on [my answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/9569/3944) on "How to make a single-page template?". Perhaps clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the code should be wrapped in `document ready` ;) Also, you're mixing `jQuery()` and `$()`. Use one or the other and if you go with `$()`, make sure it's an alias of `jQuery`.

Comment: See update to my comment^^

Comment: Hehe. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks again!

Comment: Well guys i'm kind stuck..i have made the changes as you have suggested but i can't seem to get it. Would you check my site[here](http://cheaphouses.co.ke/) The menu item i am working with is **Let us hunt for you**. When clicked it should go to banner button**Getting started** at the bottom of the page. Thanks

Comment: Your selector should be exactly `#t3-mainnav a[href^="#"]`, you had `#t3-main-nav a[href^="#t3-banner"]`. Also, you don't have any element with `id="t3-banner"`, you only have such class. Add  `id` too.